# Is it possible to use a subject before the gerund?

Tags: word-order, gerunds

Can we use a subject before the gerund?   Is it unusual?

e.g:

1. I remember **this** **book** having been read before.
2. **People** having found money was a good thing..
3. **terrorists** killing people is a violation of human rights.

Comment: They seem fine to me.

Comment: Does sentence 2 sound good?  thanks!

Comment: Yes.  I'm not sure what 200_success thinks is wrong with it.

Comment: 2 just seems unnatural and awkward or illogical upon first reading. It doesn't get much better with repeated readings.

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 1 is a grammatically valid sentence in passive voice.  However, it is logically awkward — what you remember is not so much the book itself, but the act of reading it.  Therefore, the verb "read" should be emphasized.  The passive voice construction does the opposite, and puts the focus on "this book".  I recommend using the active voice:

> I remember having read this book before.

---

Your original Sentence 2 ("People having found money was a good job..") made no sense at all; I would consider it incorrect.

The version you added in Rev 4 of the question ("People having found money was a good thing..") is acceptable (except for the extra punctuation).

---

Sentence 3 is fine and natural, except for capitalization and punctuation.

Comment: What about "People having found **their** money was a good thing"? Maybe is awkward but is it grammatical?